# Удаление одинаковых объектов в определенных столбцах postgresql 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select column_1, column_2, column_3
from test_table;
```

Запрос который возвращает таблицу с 3 столбцами.

```
aaa 11 123
bbb 12 232
ccc 14 222
aaa 16 222
sss 19 333
bbb 19 331
aaa 20 999
```

Необходимо эту таблицу вывести следующим образом

```
aaa 11 123
    16 222
    20 999
bbb 12 232
    19 331
ccc 14 222
sss 19 333
```

Как можно это сделать?. Я предполагаю это нужно делать через order by но как то нужно получить промежуточные результаты.

Answer (score 0):

Используем оконные функции и подзапрос:

```
select case when rnk=1 then column1 else '' end column1, column2, column3 from (
  select row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column3) rnk, 
         column1, column2, column3 from test_table) t
 order by t.column1, rnk
```

[Фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e1c43/7)

Comment: А если необходимо будет так сделать с несколькими колонками. В нашем примере  не только первую колонку к такому виду привести, но и вторую тоже.

Comment: Добавляете вторую оконную функцию с партишном по второй колонке и в условии отображения второй колонки прописываете её результат